# Extracting duration using System.Window.Media.MediaPlayer sometimes doesn't work

Tags: media-player, duration, windows-media-player

I use the System.Window.Media.MediaPlayer Object to extract the duration of various local soundfiles in my windows application.

```
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0);
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

player.Open(new Uri(filename));

if (player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
{
    duration = player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
}

player.Close();
```

But the problem is that sometimes (even with same files and at different code place) the duration is "0".

Has anyone an idea?

Thx 4 answers

Answer (score 2):

first check if file was loaded. simply monitor for an `OpenStateChanged` event. Then call something like

`duration = player.CurrentMedia.Duration;`

or for a string result:

`duration = player.CurrentMedia.DurationString;`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you finally found the solution to your problem. Anyway I leave an answer for those arriving here.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.naturalduration.aspx):

> Remarks: NaturalDuration cannot be determined until after MediaOpened has occurred.

So you have to wait until media is actually opened:

```
player.MediaOpened += new EventHandler(player_MediaOpened);

...

private void player_MediaOpened(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
    {
        duration = player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
    }
    else
    {
        // Duration is Automatic
    }
}
```